# Does mySQL Replication: Master DB Name has to be the same as the Slave DB name?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have set the Master DB Name as MDB & in the Slave server I set to replicate-do-db=SDB <-- this did not work? But when I set it up as the same DB name it works. Is there any solution out there to setup 1 master db with 2 different slaves but in the same server??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify the [`replicate-rewrite-db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db) option:

```
--replicate-rewrite-db=from_name->to_name
```

> Tells the slave to translate the default database (that is, the one
>   selected by USE) to to_name if it was from_name on the master. Only
>   statements involving tables are affected (not statements such as
>   CREATE DATABASE, DROP DATABASE, and ALTER DATABASE), and only if
>   from_name is the default database on the master. This does not work
>   for cross-database updates. To specify multiple rewrites, use this
>   option multiple times. The server uses the first one with a from_name
>   value that matches. The database name translation is done before  the
>   --replicate-* rules are tested.

If you are only replicating certain databases, you will need to specify the [`replicate-do-db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db).  Note that the argument to this is the name of the database after the rename operation applied by `replicate-rewrite-db`:

```
--replicate-do-db=db_name
```

Comment: where do I put the replicate-rewrite-db code in the master side or slave side??

Comment: plzz define weather to include replicate-do-db with replicate-rewrite-db or not?

Answer (score 0):

### MySQL Replication with different database names

Add the following to the logging and replication section of your MySQL configuration file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf), I inserted mine right above **relay-log**.

`replicate-rewrite-db    = db_1->db_2`

Replace **db_1** with the database's name being replicated from the remote master and **db_2** with the destination database's name.

- Restart the MySQL server (`/etc/init.d/mysql restart`)
- Access the MySQL shell (`mysql -h localhost -u root -p`)
- Check the Slave status (`SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`)